# Send signal to web-server on tab close?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, signals, dom-events

**Can I force the sending of a 'CLOSE' signal to my server when a tab directed at my website is closed?**

(thinking it might be possible with a Javascript alert on close-tab signal)

Comment: Should mention that there is one client to the web-server; and the `CLOSE` signal should shutdown server. So can't use idle timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Hey your looking for the html window attribute `onunload` so for example `< body onunload="javascriptfunction2server()">` will run your javascript function when a tab/window is closed by user (or directed to new page)